# expose HTTP endpoint with micrometer

Tags: java, prometheus, micrometer

I am trying to use micrometer to expose an endpoint to prometheus. I am not using Spring in any shape or form.
In the following article https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus they are using the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` as example.
How can a self written HTTPServlet look like?

I have no clue as where to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this anything to do with micrometer or is the question actually how to expose an HTTP endpoint in Java?

There are a lot of ways to do this, but since you are asking specifically for servlets:

- You need to create your own `Servlet` by extending [`HttpServlet`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and register it
- Here's a generic example to do it: [A Simple Servlet Example – (write, deploy, run)](https://mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/)
- Basically you need to send back what you get from `prometheusRegistry.scrape()`
- You can also take a look at [`MetricsServlet`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/29dfd0a2bf9b93282764d31447b843a1d36d4f10/simpleclient_servlet/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/MetricsServlet.java) in Prometheus client
  (does not use Micrometer's `PrometheusRegistry`)

Also, let me leave this here as a general advice: always make sure that your `InputStream`/`OutputStream`/`Reader`/`Writer`/etc. is property closed (`finally` block or `try-with-resource`, in this case you will have a (`Print`)`Writer`).